# What incentives exist for a full node to provide block headers to a light client?

Tags: networking, light-client

As I understand it, substrate light clients (a.k.a [smoldot](https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot)) connect to full nodes in order to receive block headers.

I am wondering about what incentives these full nodes have to keep providing block headers to light nodes and what are their costs?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are no incentives, but it is something that will need to be thought through, designed, and implemented in time.